# Java: How to output two words in the same string onto separate lines?

Tags: java, system.out

I am trying to enter the first and last name in one string and then display the first and last name on separate lines.  I thought the nextLine(); command would work but is not displaying the first and last name on separate lines

```
    String full_name;

    System.out.println("Please enter your first and last name?");

     full_name = c.nextLine();

    System.out.printf("Your name is: "+ full_name);
```

Comment: what is 'c' in c.nextLine() ?

Comment: Give us an example of what you want the console to look like, that way we can give you an exact answer rather than just guessing.

Comment: c is the variable that the Scanner command searches for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try ...

```
System.out.print("Your name is: "+ full_name.replace(" ", "\n"));
```

Comment: Ok thank you that worked.  I just dont understand why nextLine(); did not work, my professor said that is what it does i believe.

Comment: well, since c is Scanner nextLine() would `read` the next line. Printing on console is not the job of scanner.

Answer (score 2):

Presuming that `c` is a `Scanner` set to listen to `System.in`, then by virtue of it being on the input stream, it wouldn't have an effect on the output stream.

Instead, if you wanted to print the first and last name that was entered, and we presume that a first and last name is separated by a single space (may want logic for middle names), you can write this.

```
String[] brokenName = full_name.split(" ");
System.out.printf("Your name is:\n%s\n%s", full_name[0], full_name[1]);
```